Sensitivity on write operation of register
On some microcontrollers' peripherals we have a write-sensitive and read-sensitive registers. For example, serial port has a TX register, and write operation of them triggers some actions. I want to reach same behavior on FPGA. There is my code and a test bench that can show you desired behavior:
module serial #(
    parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8
) (
    input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] TX,
    input clk,
    output reg data_had_been_written
);

reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] tx_internal;

always @(TX) begin
    data_had_been_written <= 1;
    tx_internal <= TX; //this operation must be synchronized with posedge of clk, I hadn't do this to be more briefly.
end


always @(negedge clk) begin
    data_had_been_written <= 0;
end

endmodule

module tst_write_sensible;
parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8;

reg [DATA_WIDTH - 1:0] TX;
reg clk;
wire data_had_been_written;

serial s (
    .TX(TX),
    .clk(clk),
    .data_had_been_written(data_had_been_written)
);

initial begin
    clk = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1)
        #1 clk = ~clk;
end

initial begin
    #2 TX = 4; //Posedge of data_had_been_written must be triggered here
    #2 TX = 5; //Posedge of data_had_been_written must be triggered here
    #2 TX = 5; //Posedge of data_had_been_written must be triggered here
    #2 TX = 6; //Posedge of data_had_been_written must be triggered here
    #2 TX = 7; //Posedge of data_had_been_written must be triggered here
end

endmodule

How can I reach desired behavior?

Show us a test bench for the desired behavior.

@dave_59, I've added, please look.


Can an input be a reg?

No, inputs don't retain state.
See What’s the deal with those wire’s and reg’s in Verilog by Dave Rich for more on wires & regs.

The posted code attempts to assign the variable TX (which is an input) as
a flip flop.
This produces a error at compile time; the post does not compile on any of the four commercial simulator's on EDA Playground edaplayground.
Change
input reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] TX

to
output reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] TX

To fix the error.
You could also use a local variable if you don't want an output.

Also
A recommendation against assigning and detecting x this way for synthesis workflows.
Assigning and detecting x will not behave the same way in synthesis workflows and simulation workflows.  There are very few occasions where assigning and detecting x makes sense in FPGA synthesis workflows.  Maybe in a nested if or case statement when attempting to force extra optimization, or something like that.
